# How to ignore letters in regex

Tags: python, regex, date

I have a date string like this -

```
bla bla, janaury 1932 bla bla
```

I want to get only **jan 1932** using regex (January has spelling mistakes in it)

If I use `jan [a-z]*\s\d{4}` , obviously I get - "janaury 1932"

Comment: what about `jan [a-z]{3}\s\d{4}`?

Comment: I don't think it's obvious because you're matching a sequence with a space after `jan`.

Answer (score 5):

Capture the parts you need, then join:

```
import re
s = 'bla bla, janaury 1932 bla bla'
m = re.search(r"\b([^\W\d_]{3})\w*\s+([0-9]{4})\b", s)
if m:
    print("{} {}".format(m.group(1),m.group(2))) # => jan 1932
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UmGUR1)

**NOTE**: If you want to make sure you match one of the month names, use an alternation based regex:

```
m = re.search(r"\b(j(?:an|u[nl])|feb|ma[ry]|a(?:pr|ug)|sep|oct|nov|dec)\w*\s+([0-9]{4})\b", s, re.I)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XAim4Q/2) and [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/aETGP7).

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (to match `january` as a whole word)
- `([^\W\d_]{3})` - Group 1: exactly 3 letters
  OR
- `(j(?:an|u[nl])|feb|ma[ry]|a(?:pr|ug)|sep|oct|nov|dec)` - the first 3 letters of any English month name
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `([0-9]{4})` - Group 2: four ASCII digits
- `\b` - a word boundary (so that the four digits matched could not be followed with a letter, digit or `_`).

With `"{} {}".format(m.group(1),m.group(2)`, the `jan` and 4 digits are concatenated into the result needed.

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed What do you mean "not defined"? If you expect month names, you may just use an alternation pattern like `(jan|feb|ma[ry]|apr|ju[nl]|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)`. Compile the regex with `re.I` to match in a case insensitive way then.

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed: OK, I updated with 2 variants: 1) less restrictive, 2) for messed up inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you do not want to ignore all letters, but only some of them.

Your expression was pretty close. 
You can use this expression to capture what you want (you capture stuff putting it between ():

```
(jan).*(\d{4})
```

and recover captured stuff with this

```
.group(1) .group(2)
```